# warning in python with MySQLdb

Tags: python, warnings, mysql

when I use MySQLdb get this message:

```
/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb/__init__.py:34: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated from sets import ImmutableSet
```

I try filter the warning with

```
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="the sets module is deprecated from sets import ImmutableSet")
```

but, I not get changes.
any suggestion?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings): you could filter your warning this way, so that if other warnings are caused by an other part of your code, there would still be displayed:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
    import MySQLdb
[...]
```

but as said by Alex Martelli, the best solution would be to update MySQLdb so that it doesn't use deprecated modules.

Answer (score 1):

What release of MySQLdb are you using?  I think the current one (1.2.3c1) should have it fixed see [this bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2156977&group_id=22307&atid=374932) (marked as fixed as of Oct 2008, 1.2 branch).

Comment: I have __version__ = "1.2.2", maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @juanpablo, maybe, though it's weird since you do have the last full-release (that "c1" means "release candidate 1" for 1.2.3) and the 1.2 branch SHOULD have fixed the problem 1+ year ago. The bug report I point to includes a simple fix to the relevant .py files, maybe you want to do those small edits yourself and fix the problem (which is better than just suppressing warnings!-), basically you need to skip that import and bind the `frozenset` built-in to that `ImmutableSet` old, obsolete, deprecated name!